# Error with gnome on virtual machine

Tags: 18.04

OS: Ubuntu 18.03 LTS
this is the error I get on startup and also the shell won't start:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/betteradmin/.cache’: Permission denied
-bash: /home/betteradmin/.cache/wslu/integration: Permission denied
betteradmin@FBIVan:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like to me that your VM machine files are not having enough permission. I suggest you to give the permission of 777 to try it out. And then start the VM. Or might be possible that you need to change the ownership of the directory to the respective "root" i guess.

You need to go to the directory where the VM files are and then assign the proper permission and ownership. It might work.

Comment: Nvm I know what you mean now {REPLY TO OWN COMMENT} and how the F###k do I do that

Comment: chown root:root <name of the dir or file to which you want to change the ownership>

Comment: chmod 777 <name of dir or file> i guess you should check the permission. And you need to provide more data.

Comment: betteradmin@FBIVan:~$ chown root:root /home/betteradmin/.cache/wslu/integration

chown: cannot access '/home/betteradmin/.cache/wslu/integration': Permission denied

betteradmin@FBIVan:~$

Comment: @nottellin (now imma head to bed I check back in morn)

Comment: okay the error messages are gone but now I need to deal with the shell not starting